# My infinite scroll append two times with Safari and make duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, safari

I have problem with my infinite scroll with Safari. 
He run two times and make duplicate. 
This is my code :

```
    $window.scroll(function(){

    if (($document.height() - $window.height()) == $window.scrollTop()) {
        $('#loading-more svg').show();

        jQuery.post(
            ajaxurl,
            {
                'action': 'load_more',
                'offset': offset
            },
            function(response){
                $('#loading-more svg').hide();
                $('.load-more').append(response);
                if (response) {
                    offset = offset + 4;
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Do you have solution ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: like your other post, bind and unbind the specific event shud solve ur issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbind that specific scroll event till your delayed operation is completed to prevent accumulating more of the event triggers which create the duplication behaviour as in your case.

```
$window.scroll(myEventFn);
function myEventFn() {
    if (($document.height() - $window.height()) == $window.scrollTop()) {
        $window.unbind("unbind", myEventFn); //unbind specific event
        $('#loading-more svg').show();

        jQuery.post(
            ajaxurl, {
                'action': 'load_more',
                'offset': offset
            },
            function(response) {
                $('#loading-more svg').hide();
                $window.scroll(myEventFn); //bind back the event
                $('.load-more').append(response);
                if (response) {
                    offset = offset + 4;
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var scrolled = true;
$window.scroll(function(){

    if ( scroll == true; ) {
        scrolled = false;
        if (($document.height() - $window.height()) == $window.scrollTop()) {
            $('#loading-more svg').show();

            jQuery.post(
                ajaxurl,
                {
                    'action': 'load_more',
                    'offset': offset
                },
                function(response){
                    $('#loading-more svg').hide();
                    $('.load-more').append(response);
                    if (response) {
                        offset = offset + 4;
                        scrolled = true;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```